# Aggregating points into polylines, sorted by timestamp using GeoPandas/Python

Tags: python, geopandas, aggregation, sorting

I have a geodataframe that contains positions (point geometries). For each position, we know the individual's id (id_individ), DOY (doy), year (année) and timestamp.

[image: entry]

I want to aggregate the geometries (and sort them by timestamp) to reconstitute individual tracks, grouped by id and DOY. The expected result is a geodataframe where the geometry column contains Linestrings.
So far, I've tried this python command:

```
tracks = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_species.groupby(['id_individ', 'doy', 'year']).geometry.agg(unary_union).reset_index(), geometry="geometry", crs=df_species.crs)
```

I get :

[image: Output]

I can't sort the points by timestamp at aggregation time and then generate a Linestring. I know it's possible to do this in SQL, but I'm looking for a way to do it in Python with Geopandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sort](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by id and date, [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) id and [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) into [linestrings](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.LineString.html):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/gps_points.shp")

#A set of points for two id's with a date column    :

#df.head()
    #     id                   geometry       date
    # 36   1  POINT (-8.13625 54.75627) 2020-01-17
    # 17   2  POINT (11.42834 45.70536) 2022-03-18
    # 15   2  POINT (13.65557 48.35051) 2022-03-16
    # 32   1  POINT (-9.85519 63.64919) 2020-01-13
    # 2    2  POINT (12.77191 52.25444) 2022-03-03
    

#Sort by id and date, groupby id and pass all the points for each id to LineString
df2 = df.sort_values(by=["id","date"]).groupby("id", as_index=False).agg({"geometry":lambda x: LineString(x)})

#The geometry column definition and crs gets lost, reset them:
df2 = df2.set_geometry("geometry") 
df2 = df2.set_crs("EPSG:4326")

#df2
#    id                                           geometry
# 0   1  LINESTRING (-17.97494 65.30383, -17.23383 66.3...
# 1   2  LINESTRING (9.55470 55.21967, 10.83302 53.2404...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note : an error can occur if there is only one row after aggregating. To avoid this you need to filter the dataframe :df_species = df_species .groupby('id_track').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)